# PDF Repair Tool (Gratis)

Tags: gratis, pdf, repair

I'm looking for a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) PDF repair tool, preferably for Windows.

If there is a great one for Android, that would be acceptable too.

I've done a fair amount of searching, and I haven't found anything that isn't from a very questionable source.

I would prefer something that is portable (no installer), but that is not a requirement.

The file I need to recover is likely under 10 pages, so a page limit is acceptable.

Comment: I would think that it depends what is wrong with the pdf.

Comment: @SteveBarnes The error when trying to view the file is *Error (PDF Structure Library): Invalid reference table (xref)*

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I did not.  I think in that particular case, I used a hex editor to gather as many text strings as I could identify, and copied those strings to a text file.

Comment: When in doubt, search SourceForge (was dying, tried to revive, not doing great, but still has a lot that wasn't moved to ...), GitHub (the current undisputed king), apparently [Freecode, aka Freshmeat is dead](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/28hj6r/freecode_aka_freshmeat_is_dead/), and it is so long since I looked that I did not even know that FreshMeat had been reborn as FreeCode :-)  Any others? I must get a list of the best of such sites.  Also, no use in this case, but I tend to trawl https://alternativeto.net/

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Yes, there are still some wonderful goodies on SourceForge, although many of the projects there are no longer maintained. I have a substantial list of sites that I use to find open-source software, but the big one, as you mentioned, is now GitHub. There's also GitLab and Bitbucket. F-Droid isn't a production environment, but it's a great resource for open-source software.  `alternative.to` was a good starting point, but it didn't make it. As you mentioned, `alternativeto.net` is pretty good, especially if you are willing to look beyond the top few listings on any page.

Comment: Of course, ***this site*** should be top of the list :-) And we should be striving to keep it so, but it doesn;t hurt to have [a little list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWo_3CIcTBQ)  GitHub, of course, has a [list of lists](https://github.com/topics/awesome)  Aaaargh!! Don't click on that! ***DON'T CLICK ON THAT !!!*** I already have over 50 tabs open to read as soon as I finish this; I have barely begun an that lists of lists & every open tab is another list of extremely fascinating & helpful stuph !!! Don't expect so see me on this site for a few weeks